# How to remove date value from td if is the same date value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have a table where my date value repeats for each table row. I tried to fix this problem with SQL inside of my query but that can not be done there so I'm looking for other solution with Javascript or JQuery to fix this problem. So I would like to remove date values if they repeat but if date value changed in my td I would keep it. Here is how table looks:

```
Date            Time
10/19/2016  8:00 AM - 8:30 AM       
10/19/2016  8:30 AM - 9:00 AM       
10/19/2016  9:00 AM - 9:30 AM       
10/19/2016  9:30 AM - 10:00 AM      
10/19/2016  10:00 AM - 10:30 AM         
10/19/2016  10:30 AM - 11:00 AM         
10/19/2016  11:00 AM - 11:30 AM         
10/19/2016  11:30 AM - 12:00 PM         
10/19/2016  12:00 PM - 12:30 PM         
10/19/2016  12:30 PM - 1:00 PM      
10/19/2016  1:00 PM - 1:30 PM       
10/19/2016  1:30 PM - 2:00 PM       
10/20/2016  9:00 AM - 9:20 AM       
10/20/2016  9:20 AM - 9:40 AM       
10/20/2016  9:40 AM - 10:00 AM      
10/20/2016  10:00 AM - 10:20 AM         
10/20/2016  10:20 AM - 10:40 AM         
10/20/2016  10:40 AM - 11:00 AM         
10/20/2016  11:00 AM - 11:20 AM         
10/20/2016  11:20 AM - 11:40 AM         
10/20/2016  11:40 AM - 12:00 PM         
10/20/2016  12:00 PM - 12:20 PM         
10/20/2016  12:20 PM - 12:40 PM         
10/20/2016  12:40 PM - 1:00 PM      
10/20/2016  1:00 PM - 1:20 PM       
10/20/2016  1:20 PM - 1:40 PM       
10/20/2016  1:40 PM - 2:00 PM       
10/20/2016  2:00 PM - 2:20 PM       
10/20/2016  2:20 PM - 2:40 PM
```

As you can see above this is very confusion with all dates listed for each row, I would like to keep just first date value for each date. Something like this:

```
Date            Time
10/19/2016  8:00 AM - 8:30 AM       
            8:30 AM - 9:00 AM       
            9:00 AM - 9:30 AM       
            9:30 AM - 10:00 AM      
            10:00 AM - 10:30 AM         
            10:30 AM - 11:00 AM         
            11:00 AM - 11:30 AM         
            11:30 AM - 12:00 PM             
            12:00 PM - 12:30 PM         
            12:30 PM - 1:00 PM      
            1:00 PM - 1:30 PM       
            1:30 PM - 2:00 PM       
10/20/2016  9:00 AM - 9:20 AM       
            9:20 AM - 9:40 AM       
            9:40 AM - 10:00 AM      
            10:00 AM - 10:20 AM         
            10:20 AM - 10:40 AM         
            10:40 AM - 11:00 AM         
            11:00 AM - 11:20 AM         
            11:20 AM - 11:40 AM         
            11:40 AM - 12:00 PM         
            12:00 PM - 12:20 PM         
            12:20 PM - 12:40 PM         
            12:40 PM - 1:00 PM      
            1:00 PM - 1:20 PM       
            1:20 PM - 1:40 PM       
            1:40 PM - 2:00 PM       
            2:00 PM - 2:20 PM       
            2:20 PM - 2:40 PM
```

Here is my code that I currently use to output values to the screen:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time Slots</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ~[tlist_sql;
                Select to_char(PTC_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy'),SLOT_LABEL
                From EVENT_SLOTS 
                Where e.EVENT_ID = '145'
                Order by PTC_DATE, DISPLAY_ORDER;]
            <tr>
                <td>~(PTC_DATE)</td>
                <td>~(SLOT_LABEL)</td>
            </tr>
            [/tlist_sql]
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What would be if it's even possible to remove duplicate date values in my Date td tag? If anyone can help please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by table definition?

Comment: Column names and data types. (And table names.)

Comment: Column names are PTC_DATE and SLOT_LABEL, table is EVENT_SLOTS. Data type is DATE and STRING(50).

Comment: So you store values like '9:30 AM - 10:00 AM' as string(50)?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I do not use time to store them in DB.

Comment: Too bad. Hard to order those values... AM/PM, one or two digits for hour part...

Comment: I know, that was the most difficult part for me in this project when I was creating those time slots. I could not use JQuery to get time picker I had to create them with pure Java Script and define AM/PM only from 7am up to 5pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if you really want to manipulate this in jquery/javascript add class to each date `<td>` tag and run this code:

```
    var placeholder = '';
$(".date").each(function() {
  if (placeholder != '') {
    if (placeholder == $(this).text()) {
      $(this).text("");
    } else {
      placeholder = $(this).text();
    }
  } else {
    placeholder = $(this).text();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4v387nu/

Comment: this works! I just tested on my page and all duplicates are removed from the screen. I was wondering is it possible to put <hr> tag after duplicate is found? That way user can see where is the break in between different dates? Thanks one more time for your time and help!

Comment: @user3023588, you can do something like this: $(this).append("<hr>"); and then do some styling with css: https://jsfiddle.net/j4v387nu/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could update the date values with blank using something similar to below:

```
  update table1 a 
  set a.date ='' 
  where a.time > (
                   select min(time) 
                   from table1 
                   where date=a.date
                  )
```

Using incremental column for filtering will do the job

```
   update table1 a 
   set a.date ='' 
   where a.ID > (
               select min(ID) 
               from table1 
               where a.date=date

              )
```